# Impossible upload a file to google bucket with a service account which has a condition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-bucket

Has anyone worked with a google bucket + iam + condition?
Created a service account with the `Storage Admin` role and added the condition:

```
resource.type == "storage.googleapis.com/Bucket" &&
resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/stagestorage")
```

[image]

While loading the file to storage, I get

> Error 403: my-sa@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object, forbidden...

But if only `resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/stagestorage")` is left in the condition, then everything works. I also tried changing the role to `Storage Object Admin`, but the result is the same.

Maybe 'resource.type' is a redundant condition?

Comment: Try `resource.type == "storage.googleapis.com/Bucket" &&
resource.name.startsWith("projects/_/buckets/stagestorage")`

Comment: The issue is that you are incorrectly using quotes.

Comment: Oh, I'm bad, I forgot to delete the first bracket. In original it looks like this:
resource.type == \"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket\" && resource.name.startsWith(\"projects/_/buckets/unitely-stage\"). But it doesn't work.

Comment: `Oh, I'm bad, I forgot to delete the first bracket…`

Could you edit your question and post the actual conditions you used?
What error do you get with the `Storage Admin` role? What error do you get with the `Storage Object Admin` role?

Comment: Who or what is using said Service Account? Perhaps, another GCP product? Ie. some developers miss to fully configure GKE’s [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/workload-identity) for GKE to use other GCPs products.